# Display Dropdown values depending on Conditions in php

Tags: php

Hi all i am trying to  display the course list in drop down depending on company id.

I have 8 courses. in that i have one course name called PEI Course(course id is 33). When i am trying to assign courses to user that course will appear only for company PEI (company id is 14) and i have another course name called ppc course(course id is 46). When i am trying to assign courses to user that course will appear only  for 3 companies that is ex: a(company id is 19),b(company id is 20),c(company id is 26).

How can i do that can any one help me.

Here is my drop down Code:

```
<select name="courseid" id="courseid" class="form-control" required>     
    <?php
    $sql = "select id,fullname from {course} where id NOT IN(1,33) ";
    $courses = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);
    ?>

    <option value="">Choose Course</option>
    <?php
    if (sizeof($courses)): foreach ($courses as $row):
            $coursename = $row->fullname;
            ?> 
            <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->fullname; ?></option> 
            <?php
        endforeach;
    endif;
    ?>        
</select>
```

Can anyone help me how can i do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should tackle this problem at the database level. Create two tables (`company` and `courses`). Also create a third table called `company_courses` and enter each company with their respective course. I am assuming you have an existing `users` table and your `users` table has a `company_id` column. So, now you can query your `company_courses` table with a `user->company_id`. I think it's better to design your system this way.

Comment: cant we do it in php  using if condition with compare of companyid?

Comment: You can...but what if you want to do it again in another page? Doing it your way is not best practice but let me come up with something for you. Stand by.

Comment: like this if($companyid =="14")
   or elseif(($companyid ===19) && ($companyid ===20) &&  ($companyid ===26))
         {

Comment: ok i have tried like that still need to check whether its working or not will it work?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer you go the database route as I stated in the comment section. You could try this in the mean time though:

```
$courses = [44, 52, 67];
$companyId = 14;
$pei = "<option value='33'>33</option>";
$ppc = "<option value='46'>46</option>";
?>

<select name="courseid" id="courseid" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="">Choose Course</option>
    <?php
    if($companyId == 14){
        echo $pei;
    }elseif (in_array($companyId, array(19, 20, 26))) {
        echo $ppc;
    }
    foreach ($courses as $row) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row; ?>"><?php echo $row; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>

Change the `$companyId` to 19 and test again.
```